# Ghostscript 9.15 - Files splitted from a large .pdf file are corrupted

Tags: pdf, type-conversion, ghostscript, postscript

I'm using a tool that splits large .pdf files into smaller parts and it's using Ghostscript to reduce the size of the new generated files. 
Today I ran the tool to segmentate a pdf from itext-paulo-155 and all the files seemed to have been created correctly. However when I select and copy the chars from the new and small .pdf files into a text editor, these are all corrupted like this:

```
ỘỔỎồỌỐỗ ờ. ỌộỏỌ
ọχτφσ Ởωχκκω, Ọυω.  • Ọσσ Ọχητχ, ỘỔ 
ζσιζς@βςξθν.κιβ •
```

I updated my ghostscript version to the newest one 9.15 and it's still happening. I've set the following params in my code:

`gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH  -dQUIET -sOutputFile=`

Apparently Ghostscript cannot support this kind of .pdf files that appear to be common ones, they're not scanned images. Do you have any idea what can cause this weird behaviour and how can I do to make ghostscript not corrupt the chars?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You are not 'splitting' a PDF file, you are creating a number of brand new PDF files from the original PDF. Ghostscript interprets the PDF file, producing a sequence of graphical primitives, and then the pdfwrite device reassembles these primitives into a brand new output file.

**Because** you are doing this, you are also able to apply controls which process the graphics primitives, for example subsetting fonts, downscaling images, converting colour spaces etc.

But the files you output are not the same as the original file. If you want to split the file up, use something like pdftk or MuPDF which does exactly that. The applications will leave the data untouched and simply spit it out into new files, Ghostscript will not.

Now, if the file renders correctly on screen it is **NOT** corrupted. It may not be possible to copy and paste text, but that is in no sense the same thing.

The most likely problem is that the original PDF file contained text in a font but did not include a ToUnicode CMap, however it probably included the entire font, or at the least encoded it with something like WinAnsiEncoding.

Supplied with ToUnicode mappings, Acrobat and other viewers are able to select text. If there is no ToUnicode, then they fall back to other heuristic methods. If the text is a Latin language, and the font is encoded in a Latin encoding (eg ascii) then copy and paste will work.

However, the PDFSETTINGS=/screen includes a switch to subset fonts. Once the fonts are subset they no longer have a WinAnsi, or ASCII encoding. The first character encountered is given the character code 1, the second gets the code 2 and so on. If there is a ToUnicode CMap, then this doesn't matter, because its still possible to retrieve the Unicode values for each character. However, if there is no Unicode information, then the fact that this text is no longer in ASCII values will mean that you can no longer copy/paste it intelligibly.

If you don't want that, then don't enable font subsetting, of course this means you will have to stop using -dPDFSETTINGS but its a bad idea to use that anyway IMO as it sets a number of controls all at once and most people have no idea which controls they've set, or what the implications are.

Comment: Thanks for you complete answer. The original .pdf file has Identity-H encoding. I wonder whether this has something to do. Is there another workaround for cases in which the file has this type of encoding?

Comment: No its nothing to do with the Encoding. As I already said, its most likely the lack of a ToUnicode CMap coupled with a directive to subset fonts. If you don;'t want this to happen, don't subset the fonts.